# Neo4j relationships without nodes throw error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Due to a unforeseen shutdown (and /or and error in my code) I have relationships in the database without nodes attached to it.

I think what happened was that used a MATCH statement to look up a node and subsequently a MERGE to create a relationship. For some reasons however the Match did not return a results, but the MERGE did create a relationship (apparently with a non existing node). See example below:

`MATCH (image:Image {id:{param}.id})
FOREACH (tagName in {param}.tags |                                                                            MERGE (tag:Tag {tag:tagName})                                                                     MERGE (image)-[:IS_TAGGED_AS]->(tag) // Here it creates a relationship even if no matching image is found.
)`

When I run a simple query I receive the following message:

`While loading relationships for Node[xx] a Relationship[xx] was encountered that had startNode: 0 and endNode: 0, i.e. which had neither start nor end node as the node we're loading relationships for`

I can reference the node and the relationship by Id (although the relationship does not return results) but can't Delete them.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Ideally I create a query to select all 'bad' relationships and delete them.

I am working on Neo4j 2.3.0.

Comment: How did you create the image nodes before? How many of those statements did you run? Just one? Can you run a consistency check on your store? http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/01/22/neo4j-backup-store-copy-and-consistency-check/

Comment: Why did your server crash?

Comment: hi, Thanks for your suggestion. I downloaded the enterprise version and ran the consistency check....The problem is as I suspected, due to a bug in my code a lot of non existent nodes where connected resulting in

 2016-02-19 10:03:22.822+0100 WARN  [o.n.c.ConsistencyCheckService] Inconsistencies found: ConsistencySummaryStatistics{
 Number of errors: 634345
 Number of warnings: 0
 Number of inconsistent NODE records: 436911
 Number of inconsistent RELATIONSHIP records: 90981
 Number of inconsistent RELATIONSHIP_GROUP records: 106419
 Number of inconsistent COUNTS records: 34
}

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that relationships can be created without nodes? That doesn't make sense to me. The way MERGE works is that it will match a node or relationship if it exists, otherwise it will try create a new one.

If you add PROFILE to the start of your query in the Neo4j Browser, you can see the execution plan for a query. You will see that nodes are matched first and then the relationships are matched and/or created afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not 100% sure, since the server also crashed during creates, so it could that the server was interrupted in process of creating new nodes.  Unfortunately I can't run the profile statement since it gives me the same issue.